# jQuery Deep linking

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code for some simple tabs, and am wondering if this code can be edited to enable deep linking?  I'm not using jQuery UI and would prefer not to use a plugin.
Cheers in advance for any help.

```
  $('#tabber > div').hide(); // Hide all divs

    $('#tabber ul li a').click(function () { // When link is clicked
        $('#tabber ul li').removeClass('active'); // Remove active class from links
        $(this).parent().addClass('active'); //Set parent of clicked link class to active
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); // Set currentTab to value of href attribute
        $('#tabber > div').fadeOut(200); // Hide all divs
        $(currentTab).fadeIn(200); // Show div with id equal to variable currentTab
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Anything more to it than just taking those 3 lines that select the active tab and then extracting the hash segment on page load to do the same thing? (although I'd strongly recommend the hashchange plugin).

Comment: the url changes on click eg: example.com#tab-name and user can get to that tab via same url

Comment: @BryanMoyles http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking -- good concept for web developers to understand.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a plugin?

Comment: That entire wikipedia article is basically defining 'hyperlink'. Seems like a silly term, albeit one I've also heard used.

Comment: I would use [history.js](http://balupton.github.com/history.js/demo/) to work with the `window.onhashchange` HTML5 event with graceful degradation.

Comment: Anyways, even by the wikipedia definition, this question isn't about deep linking. It's about linking to a particular 'state' of a page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with a lightweight plugin for browser compatibility and since I see anything else as a mistake: 
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

To implement deep linking you need to think of the associated logic as part of that distinct location (RESTy addressibility) and not try to do some kind of retrofitting onto existing animation code.  Or in other words, the hash change drives the UI and not the other way around.

Use that plugin and change the above logic so the UI is nothing but a standard link (something like `<a href="#tab_foo"...>`, then change the display logic to react to the hash change:

```
$(window).hashchange(function () {
    $('#tabber ul li').removeClass('active');       
    var currentTab$ = $(location.hash);
    currentTab$.parent().addClass('active');
    $('#tabber > div').fadeOut(200);
    currentTab$.fadeIn(200);
});
```

Tweak as needed (some of this certainly doesn't make sense with the actual DOM) and trigger on page load (to handle deep link).